# Show $ f(x) < x\cdot f'(x)$

Tags: derivatives, continuity

Function $f:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$ continuous on $[0,\infty)$ and differentiable at $(0,\infty)$. 
$f(0)=0$.
$f'$ is strictly increasing.

Comment: Does it involve induction method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can apply Lagrange's theorem (mean value theorem):
$$
\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=f'(c)
$$
for some $c\in(0,x)$. Since $f(0)=0$ and $x>0$, we get
$$
f(x)=xf'(c)
$$
Now apply the fact that $f'$ is strictly increasing.

Comment: All too easy.  +1

Comment: Thank you @egreg!
Lagrange helps a lot, but I still don't get how can you say that xf'(x) > f(x) knowing that f' is strictly increasing.

Comment: @Jules Since $0<c<x$, we have $f'(c)<f'(x)$ because $f'$ is strictly increasing, so also $xf'(c)<xf'(x)$.

Comment: I see it clearly now. Because we know that xf'(c)=f(x), of course.

Comment: Just one more question. Am I allowed to introduce a value c? And f'(c)? I know that it comes because of the Mean Value Theorem, but am I allowed to do that? Or is it exactly what they ask for?

Comment: @Jules Why shouldn't you be allowed to do it?

Comment: Because it seems weird that I have an x (which I don't know), and a c, which is somewhere in between 0 and x, but I still don't know the value of it...Nothing exact.

Comment: @Jules I don't understand; $x$ is any given positive number.

Comment: I think that I got it. Thank you very much! :)